# (Beginner) How to combine jQuery's option and method in one statement?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In the example, it uses jquery ui datepicker's "dateFormat" option to set the format and uses "setDate" method to set the default value.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // command 1 or statement 1
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    });

    // command 2 or statement 2
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  });
```

It works well and as expected but there are two separated commands (statements).

How to combine option and method together in one command/statement to make it more lean and clean?

Comment: did you read the jquery ui documentation ?

Comment: You can't make it simpler, because of how the plugin is designed. Setting the date involves calling a setter function, which is not part of the initialization options.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

Based on documentation at the below link:
https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

defaultDate

> Type: Date or Number or String Default: null Set the date to highlight
>   on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date
>   via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a
>   number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods
>   ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m
>   +7d'), or null for today. Multiple types supported: Date: A date object containing the default date. Number: A number of days from
>   today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents
>   yesterday. String: A string in the format defined by the dateFormat
>   option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and
>   period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for
>   weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month
>   and seven days from today.

Comment: Thank you. It works but it uses 2 options not 1 option and 1 method.

Comment: In datepicker's document (https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/), there's no "date" option. But it works and makes the code cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I guess it was defaultDate and not date.